# how to parse nested html tag using xpath

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

This is my sample html code.

using HtmlXpathSelector i need to parse the html file.

def parse(self, response):
    edxData = HtmlXpathSelector(response)

1. first i need to get all the tag which contain 
   edxData.xpath('//h2[@class = "title course-title"]')
2. inside of that tag i need to check a tag value.
3. then need to parse the div tag with class name subtitle course-subtitle copy-detail.
   how can i parse this value kindly give some suggestion

sample html response data:

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <h2 class="title course-title">
 <a href="https://www.edx.org/course/mitx/mitx-14-73x-challenges-global-poverty-1350">The Challenges of Global Poverty
 </a>
 </h2> 
 <div class="subtitle course-subtitle copy-detail">A course for those who are interested in the challenge posed by massive and persistent world poverty.
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to loop over the inner tag could be:

```
>>> for h2 in sel.xpath('//h2[@class = "title course-title"]'):
...     print h2.xpath('a')
... 
[<Selector xpath='a' data=u'<a href="https://www.edx.org/course/mitx'>]
```

or even simply:

```
>>> sel.xpath('//h2[@class = "title course-title"]/a')
[<Selector xpath='//h2[@class = "title course-title"]/a' data=u'<a href="https://www.edx.org/course/mitx'>]
```

to find another xpath, simply do:

```
>>> sel.xpath('//div[@class="subtitle course-subtitle copy-detail"]')
[<Selector xpath='//div[@class="subtitle course-subtitle copy-detail"]' data=u'<div class="subtitle course-subtitle cop'>]
```

it seem like you're using scrapy, pls also tag that question as such